# Fixing a transformer inside a metal case

Tags: design, transformer, enclosure, mechanical

[image: Hardware elements]

I want to fix this transformer inside the case you see in the picture.
It doesn't matter if it lands on the bottom, walls or the ceiling of the case, I just want to learn how to fix an element like this on a plain metal shell.
What mechanical methods and strategies do I have to follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Steven says, that transformer is intended to be PCB mounted using its solder tags.

However, if you wish to mount it to the steel panel directly a very usual way is to add a "clamp" as seen below - [copied from here](http://www.edcorusa.com/t/Mtr-Mount-Channels). You could make something similar. In this case your wiring will be on one side and you would need to connect wires to it and insulate them for safety. Using a PCB arrangement will be easier in many cases.

[image]

The makers are in Carlsbad, New Mexico, USA, but people would be able to manufacture similar clamps easily in Turkey. Note the side portions which stop the  transformer sliding out of the main loop. You could just make a simple square C sguare loop with feet relatively easily BUT the screws have to provided enough pressure and friction to stop the core sliding out sideways.

**IF** the core has mounting holes or IF it is stell and can be safely drilled, you can do something like below. If the core is ferriote it would pro=bably be destroyed by drilling. The method below and a number of others [are shown here](http://www.mercurymagnetics.com/pages/_misc/TranMounts.htm)

[image]

Comment: Russell, this is a good solution for mechanical fixing, but it doesn't solve the electrical connections. I'm dead against soldering cables directly to the transformer's pins.

Comment: @stevenvh - Use Clamps as shown. Add small PCB. Solder PCB to transformer. Solder to PCB. Add plastic etc insulating cover if desired. Roast until tender.

Answer (score 6):

The transformer doesn't have mounting tabs because it's for PCB mounting. Solder it on a piece of breadboard ("Veroboard") with some space around it, and drill 4 holes on the corners for bolts.
Since you're using a breadboard anyway, use it to mount connectors for connecting both the primary and secondary. Don't solder your power supply cable directly to the transformer pins, and especially never solder the power cord!

Make sure you mount the board high enough above the case so that the transformer pins don't come closer than 6mm from the case.

**edit** (re Federico's comment)
Doesn't apply here, but I've seen molded PCB mount transformers with a couple of mounting holes in them to screw them to the PCB. You won't see them on small transformers, like 1VA, but 10VA to 15VA transformers may have them. If the holes are there, use them! The screws will take the strain from the solder joints, which aren't meant for mechanical fixing anyway.

Comment: Be sure to make proper solder connections. A transformer weighs a lot more than other electronic components, and the solder joints may suffer mechanical strain.